# Check for a specific text in entire elastic search document as string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, scriptedfield

I am working on a use-case, wherein I want to identify which document in elastic search has a particular keyword in any of the field values (indexed as well as non-indexed).
In the case of SQL, this will be straightforward, though it will be a bit heavy. Like for Postgres, we can do:

```
select count(1) from table where data::text like '%keyword%'
```

But, in the case of elastic search, I am experimenting with the painless script.
Here is what I am trying:

- Use script filter
- Add painless script to convert entire document JSON to a string
- And, in the script, return true if the document string contains the keyword

Now, I tried different variations of following in the `scripted_field` clause to convert the entire document to string:

```
 - doc.toString()
 - doc['_source'].value
 - params._source.toString()
 - ctx._source.value.toString()
```

And, none worked.

However, I could see that retrieving individual field values is working.
So, following query gives the below mentioned result:

```
"script_fields": {
    "myfield": {
      "script": """
            return params._source.id.toString();
      """
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mytype",
  "_id": "1557e321-b6be-491f-a869-9309194af658",
  "_score": 13.808922,
  "myfield": {
    "text": [
      "1557e321-b6be-491f-a869-9309194af658"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone help in converting entire document json to string at runtime in ES?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a lot, and referring to a couple of blogs, I identified a workaround that included iterating over each field of the document and recursively builds the document string.

Here is the final working version:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        <some clause here>
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": """
              void processFields(StringBuilder sb, def x) {
               if( x != null) {
                 if (x instanceof List) {
                   for (def v: x) {
                     processFields(sb, v);
                   }
                 }
                 
                 if ((x instanceof HashMap)) {
                   HashMap map = (HashMap) x;
                   for (def v: map.values()) {
                     processFields(sb, v);
                   }
                 }
                 sb.append(x);
                 sb.append('~|~');
               }
             }
            
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (key in params._source.keySet()) {
              processFields(sb, params._source.get(key));
            }
            String s = sb.toString();
            return s.contains('<keyword-to-search-in-entire-document-string>');
"""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: make sure the delimiter used in `processFields()` is different than what you are searching for. :)

Ref for recursively iterating over all document fields:
https://alexmarquardt.com/category/painless/